# Send an Mailchimp Campaign to a specific Email

Tags: php, email, magento, mailchimp

I need to send an specific email(or campaign) to a specific email recipient from a Magento store which should send 1 day, 3 days and 5 days after the purchase of a specific product the Emails.
I have the Emails designed in Mailchimp thats why I want to use these and not redesign all emails in Magento.

Comment: MailChimp API may help in your case!

Answer (score 0):

Usually in this case I'd create a list, and subscribe the user to that list, and then use an workflow to handle the stagger the emails. In your case, 1st, 3rd and 5th day after purchase of a specific product.

You'd need to interact with MailChimp's API. Another method, which is terrible, but sometimes a necessity is to build a form in MailChimp that subscribes users to the list, and then POST to that endpoint, although, it uses GET and has issues. If you can use the API, I would do that.